# Class has two properties of the same name

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, jaxb

I have two classes. Now I have database access and want to get Lead value. Using Spring REST + JDBC.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="newlead")
public class NewLead {

     private String FIRSTNAME;

     private int LEADID;

     public String getFIRSTNAME() {
         return FIRSTNAME;
     }

     public void setFIRSTNAME(String FIRSTNAME) {
         this.FIRSTNAME = FIRSTNAME;
     }

     public int getLEADID() {
         return LEADID;
     }

     public void setLEADID(int LEADID) {
         this.LEADID = LEADID;
     }
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name="newLeads")
public class NewLeadList {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public List<NewLead> allLeads = new ArrayList<NewLead>();

    @XmlElement(required = false)
    public List<NewLead> getData() {
        return allLeads;
    }

    public void setData(List<NewLead> data) {
        this.allLeads = data;
    }
}
```

My controller

```
@Controller                 // Will be detected by <context:component-scan>
@RequestMapping("/lead")    // Will be detected by <mvc:annotation-driven> (more specifically by one of its component - RequestMappingHandlerMapping)
public class LeadController {

     @Resource(name="newLeadService")
     private com.varazo.service.NewLeadService newLeadService;

    // This method should be called for requests to "/"  
     @RequestMapping(value = "/newLeads", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/xml,application/json")
     public @ResponseBody NewLeadList getNewLead() {
         // Call service here
         NewLeadList result = new NewLeadList();
         result.setData(newLeadService.getAll());
         System.out.println("*********************LeadController Retrieving all persons ***"+result+"***yes*************"); 
         return result;
     }
```

I am getting xml like

```
</allLeads>
<allLeads>
<LEADID>0</LEADID>
</allLeads>
<allLeads>
<LEADID>0</LEADID>
</allLeads>
<allLeads>
<LEADID>0</LEADID>
</allLeads>
<allLeads>
<LEADID>0</LEADID>
</allLeads>
<data>
<LEADID>0</LEADID>
</data>
<data>
<LEADID>0</LEADID>
</data>
<data>
<LEADID>0</LEADID>
</data>
<data>
```

But I need each Lead value with firstname and id values. What is the problem here?

Comment: can you show your NewLeadService code?

Comment: For starters your mapping you put a JAXB annotation on either the field or the getter but you shouldn't mix as jaxb might get confused on what to use (field or property access).

Comment: @Denium
That also not working
@ user3487063
Service :

 public List<NewLead> getAll() {

     // logger.debug("Retrieving all persons");
  lList = leadDAOImplObj.listNewLeads();
  System.out.println("in service return==="+ lList);
     return lList;
 }
ANd in DAO class:
 public List<NewLead> listNewLeads() {
     
     // JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   return jdbcTemplate.query("select LEADID,FIRSTNAME from llead LIMIT 15", new LeadRowMapper());

Comment: Are you sure that your NewLead objects have a fiirstname?

Comment: Petar, yes I am sure.
@XmlRootElement(name="newlead")
public class NewLead {
 //@XmlAttribute(name = "FIRSTNAME")
  private String FIRSTNAME;
 //@XmlAttribute(name = "LEADID")  
  private int LEADID;
 
  public String getFIRSTNAME() {
  return FIRSTNAME;
 }
 public int getLEADID() {
  return LEADID;
 }
 public void setFIRSTNAME(String FIRSTNAME) {
   this.FIRSTNAME = FIRSTNAME;
  }
   public void setLEADID(int LEADID) {
    this.LEADID = LEADID;
   }
   
}